# /usr/bin/time cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, executable

I believe I've corrupted the **/usr/bin/time** executable as when I try to run it, this is the message that shows up:

**bash: /usr/bin/time: cannot execute binary file**

It was working till I inadvertently overwrote it.

How can I revert the changes I've made to this executable or get a fresh copy of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reinstall the relevant package, probably `time`. What is your OS/distribution?

Comment: I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Ok, then `apt-get install --reinstall time`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reinstall the time binary `/usr/bin/time`, reinstall the package that contains it.

First, find that package.

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/time 
time: /usr/bin/time
```

Then install it.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall time
```